# how to remove extra css and js link in twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter-bootstrap-rails gem for my project. Everything is well,but my question is how to remove the extra resources link in my front-end html page. In common situation，use `rails generate bootstrap:install static` command line will include all bootstrap resource files, they will slow down access time.

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
```

the extra resources just like above tags that I didn't use these features.So I need remove them.

Comment: What extra resources link? Post the HTML output.

Comment: @RichardAE the extra mean which I didn't use js or rescources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assume you're using https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, did you proper read their documentation?

In documentation on github, there are parts of how to include only few parts of [css](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less) or [js](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-javascript). You have to use LESS variables and modify js include..

I don't use this, I rather use custom builds directly from bootstrap..